# Why do my API calls not match up with how they're set to call

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm having a problem paginating through all of my data using the Quickbooks API. When using the API the only possible way that I've been able to find to request all of the data is incrementally increasing the starting position of the items requested each call until there is no data left. I've  attempted to do so by looping through the call using a for loop and changing the starting position using the for loop's variable as seen below:

```
    app.get('/getItems', function (req, res) {
    const companyID = oauthClient.getToken().realmId;
    const url = OAuthClient.environment.production;
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    let query = `select * from Item maxresults 100 startPosition ${100*i} &minorversion=59`
 
    oauthClient  
      .makeApiCall({ url: `${url}v3/company/${companyID}/query?query=${query}`})
      .then(function (authResponse) {
        console.log(authResponse.json);
      })
      
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e);
      });
    
     }
  });
```

Using the query variable, I've included ${100*i} with the hope that it would go 1,100,200,... until completed. Below is the response and it doesn't match how I would've thought.

```
{
  QueryResponse: {
    Item: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]
    ],
    startPosition: **200**,
    maxResults: 100
  },
  time: '2021-08-10T09:24:19.136-07:00'
}
{
  QueryResponse: {
    Item: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]
    ],
    startPosition: **400**,
    maxResults: 100
  },
  time: '2021-08-10T09:24:19.146-07:00'
}
{
  QueryResponse: {
    Item: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]
    ],
    startPosition: **300**,
    maxResults: 100
  },
  time: '2021-08-10T09:24:19.165-07:00'
}
{
  QueryResponse: {
    Item: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]
    ],
    startPosition: **1**,
    maxResults: 100
  },
  time: '2021-08-10T09:24:19.169-07:00'
}
{
  QueryResponse: {
    Item: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]
    ],
    startPosition: **100**,
    maxResults: 100
  },
  time: '2021-08-10T09:24:19.153-07:00'
}
```

This is only a problem due to the order of retrieving the items having an impact on the overall process. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are seeing this issue as the API calls are performed using `Promises` that are asynchronous. This means that you cannot guarantee that they will be completed in the order they were initiated.

You could create an array before your API call loop and then push each of the `authResponse.json` values into it. Once your queries are finished you could then call a `sort` function on the array and sort the objects by the `startPosition` key so they would end up in the correct order